# Getting userid based on email using DocuSign REST API

Tags: docusignapi

I was looking into the api documentation but could not find an easy way to get a userID based on an email address, is this possible?

Here is what I am trying to do.

- Get user id based on email address
- Get list of groups that the user belongs to using /accounts/{accountId}/users/{userId}
- Get the list of brands that those groups have using /accounts/{accountId}/groups/{groupId}/brands

Doing the above because I need to do a send of behalf of user and need to give the branding options for that user.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To retrieve a User Id based on an email address, you can use this DocuSign REST API operation:

```
GET https://{{env}}.docusign.net/restapi/{{version}}/accounts/{{acctId}}/users?email=johnDoe@example.com
```

If a match is found, the response will look like this:

```
{
    "users": [
        {
            "userName": "John Doe",
            "userId": "ah266e12-83a6-487c-a42b-ebad10e4cc6a",
            "userType": "CompanyUser",
            "userStatus": "active",
            "uri": "/users/ah266e12-83a6-487c-a42b-ebad10e4cc6a"
        }
    ]
}
```

***Note:***  This isn't very well-documented -- the only place I see it mentioned in the REST API guide is in the Appendix that lists the REST API methods that correspond to various SOAP API operations.  i.e., it says that if you were using the SOAP API operation **CheckAccountMember**, the REST API equivalent is https://{{env}}.docusign.net/restapi/{{version}}/accounts/{{acctId}}/users?email=<email>.

Comment: What should `acctId` be? I don't have access to it since I only know the email address

Comment: `acctId` is the ID of the DocuSign account (org) that the user is a member of. If the user whose email address you have is a member of the same DocuSign account (org) as you, that user's `acctId` will be the same as yours.

Answer (score 1):

Just an update on the issue, since i was looking for a way to get my user's userid in order to do some testing.
You can explore all of the api methods and controllers here -> https://apiexplorer.docusign.com/#/esign/restapi

Simply pick your category and then authenticate using the tool on the upper side of the page.